# CSS does not update in Spring MVC Webapp

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-mvc, frontend

I had this problem for a long time and I sometimes I would see the CSS changes on my browser sometimes not. All the files get copied to the snapshot folder and the artifact is ok too.There are no possible errors in the IDEA (I'm using intelliJ IDEA Ultimate) or in the code itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For weeks? Try opening the style sheet itself (by entering its address into the browser's address bar) and pressing F5. If it still doesn't refresh, your problem lies elsewhere.

If you update a style sheet and want to make sure it gets refreshed in every visitor's cache, a very popular method to do that is to add a version number as a GET parameter. That way, the style sheet gets refreshed when necessary, but not more often than that.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css?version=51">
```

You can add a timestamp instead of version as well which will work in same way for your future css updates.
This would work as long term solution for you.

Comment: Yeah for weeks, it's not that I focused on solving only that problem but after trying for some time now I decided to  ignored that problem and focused on the back end. Your solution worked for me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by clearing all my browsers data, this will cause your browser to reload all files. Some browsers save the front end of frequently visited pages in order to load them faster when you want to visit those pages again. So try to reset your browser or install a new one, and if everything else is alright then you will be able to see the changes.

--------------------------------UPDATE--------------------------------

The upper solution is not recommended. Try adding `version=51` to your stylesheet (that number can be any number).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css?version=51">
```

I recommend you read the answer from "Akshay Jain" in this thread.